# Add scrollbar to a tkinter window that gets contant news entry

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, frame

I have a window that call a function when a button is pressed, this function adds a row inside a new frame with 3 entries and 9 check butons, each time that it is presed a new enties were add in a new frame. I show a part of the function:

```
def agregar_fila():
    frame=Frame(root)
    frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

    #Nombre del quimico
    entry_nombre=Entry(frame)
    entry_nombre.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

    #Nombre de la marca
    entry_marca=Entry(frame)
    entry_marca.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")

    #Nombre del numero CAS
    entry_cas=Entry(frame)
    entry_cas.grid(row=0,column=2, sticky="w")
```

The general structure of my window is:

```
# Inicio la ventana
root = Tk()
root.title("Analísis de incompatibilidad de quimicos NOM-005-STPS-2017")
root.resizable(False, False)

agregar_fila = Button(frame_encabezado, text='Agregar filas', fg="Green", command=agregar_fila)
agregar_fila.grid(row=0,column=12)
mostrar = Button(frame_encabezado, text='Presentar en ventana', fg="Green",command=ventana_presentar)
mostrar.grid(row=1,column=12)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Agrego el marco con scroll

root.mainloop()
```

I show how the new rows are added:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po3st.jpg

I want that all the new frames generated by `agregar_fila()` get inside of a only scroll bar.
how can I do that?

Comment: You have both a variable and a function of the same name. I don't know if that's the cause of your problem, but it's something you should fix.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. The code you posted is missing some critical pieces.  Most importantly, you don't have any scrollbars anywhere in your code.

Comment: I have edited the post, I have placed the full code, if you want try to reproduce it.

Comment: We do not want your _full_ code. We need a _minimal_ reproducible example.  Probably half of the code you posted isn't necessary to reproduce the problem.